# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la id de un json?

Tags: php, json, webservice

Tengo este json: `[{"familia":"Pescado"},{"familia":"Carne"}]`

Me gustaría obtener la posición de cada elemento es decir obtener que:`{"familia":"Pescado"}` está en la posición 0 y que `{"familia":"Carne"}` está en la posición 1.

Answer (score 1):

Pues puedes recorrerlo con un `for`:

```js
let familias=[{"familia":"Pescado"},{"familia":"Carne"}];
for(let i=0;i < familias.length; i++){
  console.log(i,":",familias[i])
}
```

O quizá quieras hacerlo con funciones de `array object`, en este caso nos serviría un `forEach`:

```js
let familias=[{"familia":"Pescado"},{"familia":"Carne"}];
familias.forEach((familia,indice)=>{
  console.log(indice,":",familia)
})
```

Tambien puedes buscarlos por el objeto:

```js
let familias=[{"familia":"Pescado"},{"familia":"Carne"}];
let buscar_por={"familia":"Pescado"};

let indice=familias.findIndex(el => el.familia === buscar_por.familia)
console.log(buscar_por,"esta en el indice",indice)
```